# knife vsphere - issue cloning windows VM

Tags: chef-infra, knife, vsphere

I am running the following command ...

```html
knife vsphere vm clone chef-test -f TEMPLATES --template MSDN-WIN2012R2Core --bootstrap true --run-list "role[windows_server_2012_r2]"
```

However, it returns an error stating

"FATAL:Please provide Windows Guest Customization"

Can somebody please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `--cspec` option with Windows guests to select a customization template to apply on launch.

Comment: I dont have a "customization template" though, I just have a default VM template which I want to use, any ideas?

Comment: Make one: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vmadmin.doc_41/vsp_vm_guide/deploy_vms_from_templates_and_clones/t_create_a_customization_specification_for_windows.html

Comment: this may be a stupid question but do I need one if I am using Chef to provision?

Comment: Yes, from what I can see this is required by VSphere.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the option `--disable-customization` it will skip the custom specification step.

This works even with Windows template/vm sources which makes me wonder why the default is to kick back an error. Here's an example of it in practice:

```
knife vsphere vm clone newVmName \
--folder 'VmFolder' \
--template 'sourceVmOrTemplate' \
--dest-folder 'VmFolderTarget' \
--resource-pool 'Pool1' \
--ccpu 1 \
--cram 2 \
--datastorecluster 'Cluster1' \
--disable-customization
```